# Construct : Python - Print without new line

Tags: python

I am literally going crazy:

I am using the Pyhon Library : construct

What I want to acheive is to print the parsed stream on a single line, instead of having Value1 and Value 2 on different lines.
Is there a way to do so?

```
data = 0xAF

from construct import *

testOut1 = BitStruct("Value1" /Nibble, "Value2" /Nibble).parse(data) 

print(testOut1)
```

This is WHat I have :

```
Container:

Value1 = 10
Value2 = 15
```

But I would line to have something like:

```
Value1 = 10, Value2 = 15
```

Comment: You need to check the [documentation](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#fields) for how to access the values in the container. It may be as simple as `print(f"Value1 = {testOut1.Value1}, Value2 = {testOut2.Value2}")`.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is to use

```
print('hello', end='')
```

In your case our code will be:

```
data = 0xAF

from construct import *

testOut1 = BitStruct("Value1" /Nibble, "Value2" /Nibble).parse(data) 

print('Value1 =' + str(testOut1.Value1) + ',', end='')
print('Value2 =' + str(testOut1.Value2) + '', end='')
```

Or better :

```
print('Value1 =' + str(testOut1.Value1) + ',' + 'Value1 =' + str(testOut1.Value2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a string before you print it.

```
print(str(testOut1).replace("\n", ", "))
```